# boot2docker - An error occurred trying to connect when running docker version command

Tags: windows-7, docker, containers, boot2docker

When I use boot2docker to start the boot2docker-vm, then in gitbash I run the docker version command I get the following:

```
$ docker version
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): windows/amd64
FATA[0021] An error occurred trying to connect: Get     https://192.168.59.103:2376/v1.18/version: dial tcp 192.168.59.103:2376: ConnectEx tcp: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

However when I go into virtual box I see the boot2docker-vm is running.
When I stop the boot2docker-vm, & then start it myself - I can use the vm to use docker - it would be much easier to use gitbash to work with it...anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to init shell inside gitbash, use:

```
$ $(boot2docker shellinit)
```

in terminal.

Here is documentation for mac:  https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](https://x86x64.wordpress.com/2015/05/03/docker-on-windows-fata0021-an-error-occurred-trying-to-connect/) describes the configuration of **VirtualBox for Win64** systems after the boot2docker installation.

1. Change **VirtualBox Global Settings** to provide DHCP server on network adapter #2 instead of #3 with exactly the same settings as of #3
2. Change **boot2docker-vm** network configuration of the host-only network adapter from preconfigured adapter #3 to #2